# Domain Driven Naming is too long and verbose

Tags: naming

we are tackling the domain of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factoring_(finance)[factoring][1]:

> Factoring is a financial transaction and a type of debtor finance in which a business sells its accounts receivable (i.e., invoices) to a third party (called a factor) at a discount.

we are facing a major re-engineering of that central piece of domain, the "accounts receivable" part, which we currently just call `Debt` - it's short, there's no need for acronyms, everybody understands it.

However (not being a native speaker) it seems that the *actual, correct term* in that domain is "Accounts Receivable" (which we are familiar with in the accounting-domain).

Being an software engineer who rates explicit, correct naming very high, I am currently discussing with our product owner which naming to choose.
I would like to not have a monstrous wording like "Accounts Receivable" or its acronym "AccRec" all over the source code. On the other that, if that's what it really is ...

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: if you think AccountsReceivable is a monstrously long name, you must not code in Java :P

Comment: @KevinVanDyck nothing prevents you from writing Java with single character names for everything. I'd expect that when writing software in the financial field, you'd want correctness and clarity over succinct naming.

Comment: Use the names the Ubiquitous language says you must use, not the one that P.O. likes most. If the domain experts use "Accounts Receivable" to say "Debt" then use "Accounts Receivable"; the components must reflect the U.L to establish a language everybody understands. "AccRec" is a horrible name for a class whether you follow DDD or not.

Comment: Same _Ubiquitous Language_ applies for _acronyms_ or _abbreviations_: Do they convey meaning to __all stakeholders__? Consider some XML output with a tag like `<AR>`. This may be _technically_ used in a setter like `output.setAR(String accountReceivable)`. But how do you __pronounce it__ when speaking about? What does it tell you __about the meaning__? Instead let your __code communicate__ and use `setAccountReceivable(String accountName)` where the parameter became free to specify the representation of expected argument.

Answer (score 7):

The idea behind the Ubiquitous Language of DDD is that no translations take place between business-related terms. This means that if you need to present your design to the business side of the company (or they happen to see your source code), you don't need to explain to them why you have chosen those names for the domain concepts, because you are using the same terminology there as they are using in their daily discussions.

With that in mind, *the actual correct term* is how the domain experts within your company (or with the customer if you are building the software for someone else) call it. If they consistently call it "Accounts Receivable", then that is the name you should also be using. But if they find that too much of a mouth full and just refer to the same concept as "Debts" or "Invoices", then you should follow suit. If they use different names interchangeably, then there is room for negotiation.